# Query using WHERE on a fixed value performs badly. Why is this?

Tags: postgresql

I use a simple query with a WHERE on a fixed value. This query does a left join on a temporary view. For some reason this query is performing very badly. I guess that the view is being executed for every row and not only for the selected rows. When I replace the fixed value with a value from a temporary table, the query performs MUCH better (about 15-20 times faster). Why is this?

I use postgresql version 9.2.15.

I added a temporary table 'wrkovz91-selecties' with only 1 record to pass the selection-value of the WHERE instruction to the query.

The view 'view_wrk_012_000001' that is joined in the query is pretty 'heavy', because it contains a nested other view ('view_wrk_013_000006').

First create the temporary table and add one record:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE WRKOVZ91_SELECTIES
(
NR DECIMAL(006) NOT NULL,
KLANTNR DECIMAL(008),
CONSTRAINT WRKOVZ91_SELECTIES_KEY_001 PRIMARY KEY (NR)
);

INSERT INTO WRKOVZ91_SELECTIES
(NR, KLANTNR) VALUES (1, 1);
```

Then create the temporary view (with a nested view):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW view_wrk_013_000006 AS 
SELECT vrr.klantnr AS klantnr,
       UPPER(vrr.artnr) AS artnr,
       vrr.partijnr AS partijnr,
       SUM(vrr.kollo) AS colli_op_voorraad 
FROM voorraad vrr 
WHERE (vrr.status = 'A'::text)
GROUP BY 1,
         2,
         3;

CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW view_wrk_012_000001 AS 
SELECT COALESCE(wrd.klantnr,0) AS klantnr,
       COALESCE(wrd.wrkopdrnr,0) AS wrkopdrnr,
       MIN(COALESCE(wrd.recept_benodigd_colli,0) * 
COALESCE(wrk.te_produceren,0)) AS vrije_voorraad_ind,
       MIN(COALESCE(v40.colli_op_voorraad,0)) AS hulpveld 
FROM wrkopdr wrk 
LEFT JOIN wrkopdrd wrd ON wrd.klantnr = wrk.klantnr
      AND wrd.wrkopdrnr = wrk.wrkopdrnr 
LEFT JOIN view_wrk_013_000006 v40 ON v40.klantnr = 
COALESCE(wrd.klantnr_grondstof,0)
      AND v40.artnr = COALESCE(wrd.artnr_grondstof,'')
      AND v40.partijnr = COALESCE(wrd.partijnr_grondstof,0) 
LEFT JOIN artikel art ON art.klantnr = COALESCE(wrd.klantnr_grondstof,0)
      AND art.artnr = COALESCE(wrd.artnr_grondstof,'') 
WHERE wrk.status = 'A'::text
  AND art.voorraadhoudend_jn = 'J'::text
GROUP BY 1,
         2;
```

The query that performs badly is simple:

```
SELECT WRK.KLANTNR,
       WRK.WRKOPDRNR,
       WRK.MIL_UITVOER_DATUM
FROM WRKOPDR WRK 
LEFT JOIN VIEW_WRK_012_000001 V38 ON V38.KLANTNR = WRK.KLANTNR AND 
V38.WRKOPDRNR = WRK.WRKOPDRNR 
LEFT JOIN WRKOVZ91_SELECTIES S02 ON S02.NR = 1
WHERE WRK.KLANTNR = 1
LIMIT 9999;
```

The query that performs MUCH better is (note the small difference):

```
SELECT WRK.KLANTNR,
       WRK.WRKOPDRNR,
       WRK.MIL_UITVOER_DATUM
FROM WRKOPDR WRK 
LEFT JOIN VIEW_WRK_012_000001 V38 ON V38.KLANTNR = WRK.KLANTNR AND 
V38.WRKOPDRNR = WRK.WRKOPDRNR 
LEFT JOIN WRKOVZ91_SELECTIES S02 ON S02.NR = 1
WHERE WRK.KLANTNR = S02.KLANTNR
LIMIT 9999;
```

I cannot understand why the slow query is performing so badly. It takes in my test-data about 219 secondes. The fast query is taking only 12 secondes. The only difference between the 2 queries is the selection-value in the WHERE.

Does anyone have an explanation for this behaviour?

In addition, the output of the explain analyse of the slow query is:

```
Limit  (cost=19460.18..19972.73 rows=9999 width=18) (actual time=221573.343..221585.953 rows=9999 loops=1)
   ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=19460.18..20913.07 rows=28344 width=18) (actual time=221573.341..221583.701 rows=9999 loops=1)
         Hash Cond: ((wrk.klantnr = v38.klantnr) AND (wrk.wrkopdrnr = v38.wrkopdrnr))
         ->  Seq Scan on wrkopdr wrk  (cost=0.00..1240.30 rows=28344 width=18) (actual time=0.055..5.490 rows=9999 loops=1)
               Filter: (klantnr = 1::numeric)
         ->  Hash  (cost=19460.17..19460.17 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=221573.254..221573.254 rows=2621 loops=1)
               Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 113kB
               ->  Subquery Scan on v38  (cost=19460.15..19460.17 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=221570.429..221572.158 rows=2621 loops=1)
                     ->  HashAggregate  (cost=19460.15..19460.16 rows=1 width=52) (actual time=221570.429..221571.499 rows=2621 loops=1)
                           ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=14049.90..19460.14 rows=1 width=52) (actual time=225.848..221495.813 rows=6801 loops=1)
                                 Join Filter: ((vrr.klantnr = COALESCE(wrd.klantnr_grondstof, 0::numeric)) AND ((upper(vrr.artnr)) = COALESCE(wrd.artnr_grondstof, ''::text)) AND (vrr.partijnr = COALESCE(wrd.partijnr_grondstof, 0::numeric)))
                                 Rows Removed by Join Filter: 308209258
                                 ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1076.77..6011.60 rows=1 width=43) (actual time=9.506..587.824 rows=6801 loops=1)
                                       ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=1076.77..5828.70 rows=69 width=43) (actual time=9.428..204.601 rows=7861 loops=1)
                                             Hash Cond: ((wrd.klantnr = wrk.klantnr) AND (wrd.wrkopdrnr = wrk.wrkopdrnr))
                                             Filter: (COALESCE(wrd.klantnr, 0::numeric) = 1::numeric)
                                             Rows Removed by Filter: 1
                                             ->  Seq Scan on wrkopdrd wrd  (cost=0.00..3117.73 rows=116873 width=38) (actual time=0.013..65.472 rows=116873 loops=1)
                                             ->  Hash  (cost=1026.34..1026.34 rows=3362 width=16) (actual time=9.324..9.324 rows=3362 loops=1)
                                                   Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 161kB
                                                   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on wrkopdr wrk  (cost=98.31..1026.34 rows=3362 width=16) (actual time=0.850..7.843 rows=3362 loops=1)
                                                         Recheck Cond: (status = 'A'::text)
                                                         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on wrkopdr_key_002  (cost=0.00..97.47 rows=3362 width=0) (actual time=0.763..0.763 rows=3362 loops=1)
                                                               Index Cond: (status = 'A'::text)
                                       ->  Index Scan using artikel_key_001 on artikel art  (cost=0.00..2.64 rows=1 width=17) (actual time=0.037..0.043 rows=1 loops=7861)
                                             Index Cond: ((klantnr = COALESCE(wrd.klantnr_grondstof, 0::numeric)) AND (artnr = COALESCE(wrd.artnr_grondstof, ''::text)))
                                             Filter: (voorraadhoudend_jn = 'J'::text)
                                             Rows Removed by Filter: 0
                                 ->  HashAggregate  (cost=12973.14..13121.70 rows=11885 width=25) (actual time=0.027..19.661 rows=45319 loops=6801)
                                       ->  Seq Scan on voorraad vrr  (cost=0.00..12340.71 rows=63243 width=25) (actual time=0.456..122.855 rows=62655 loops=1)
                                             Filter: (status = 'A'::text)
                                             Rows Removed by Filter: 113953
 Total runtime: 221587.386 ms
(33 rows)
```

The output of the explain analyse of the fast query is:

```
Limit  (cost=56294.55..57997.06 rows=142 width=18) (actual time=445.371..12739.474 rows=9999 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=56294.55..57997.06 rows=142 width=18) (actual time=445.368..12736.035 rows=9999 loops=1)
         Join Filter: ((v38.klantnr = wrk.klantnr) AND (v38.wrkopdrnr = wrk.wrkopdrnr))
         Rows Removed by Join Filter: 26206807
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..1532.01 rows=142 width=18) (actual time=0.055..18.652 rows=9999 loops=1)
               Join Filter: (wrk.klantnr = s02.klantnr)
               ->  Index Scan using wrkovz91_selecties_key_001 on wrkovz91_selecties s02  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=14) (actual time=0.021..0.021 rows=1 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (nr = 1::numeric)
               ->  Seq Scan on wrkopdr wrk  (cost=0.00..1169.44 rows=28344 width=18) (actual time=0.026..11.905 rows=9999 loops=1)
         ->  Materialize  (cost=56294.55..56296.25 rows=68 width=64) (actual time=0.044..0.380 rows=2621 loops=9999)
               ->  Subquery Scan on v38  (cost=56294.55..56295.91 rows=68 width=64) (actual time=441.797..443.503 rows=2621 loops=1)
                     ->  HashAggregate  (cost=56294.55..56295.23 rows=68 width=52) (actual time=441.795..442.848 rows=2621 loops=1)
                           ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=14525.30..56293.70 rows=68 width=52) (actual time=255.847..433.386 rows=6801 loops=1)
                                 Hash Cond: ((COALESCE(wrd.klantnr_grondstof, 0::numeric) = v40.klantnr) AND (COALESCE(wrd.artnr_grondstof, ''::text) = v40.artnr) AND (COALESCE(wrd.partijnr_grondstof, 0::numeric) = v40.partijnr))
                                 ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1076.77..42541.70 rows=68 width=43) (actual time=10.356..171.502 rows=6801 loops=1)
                                       ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=1076.77..5794.04 rows=13863 width=43) (actual time=10.286..91.471 rows=7862 loops=1)
                                             Hash Cond: ((wrd.klantnr = wrk.klantnr) AND (wrd.wrkopdrnr = wrk.wrkopdrnr))
                                             ->  Seq Scan on wrkopdrd wrd  (cost=0.00..3117.73 rows=116873 width=38) (actual time=0.014..38.276 rows=116873 loops=1)
                                             ->  Hash  (cost=1026.34..1026.34 rows=3362 width=16) (actual time=10.179..10.179 rows=3362 loops=1)
                                                   Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 161kB
                                                   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on wrkopdr wrk  (cost=98.31..1026.34 rows=3362 width=16) (actual time=0.835..8.667 rows=3362 loops=1)
                                                         Recheck Cond: (status = 'A'::text)
                                                         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on wrkopdr_key_002  (cost=0.00..97.47 rows=3362 width=0) (actual time=0.748..0.748 rows=3362 loops=1)
                                                               Index Cond: (status = 'A'::text)
                                       ->  Index Scan using artikel_key_001 on artikel art  (cost=0.00..2.64 rows=1 width=17) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=1 loops=7862)
                                             Index Cond: ((klantnr = COALESCE(wrd.klantnr_grondstof, 0::numeric)) AND (artnr = COALESCE(wrd.artnr_grondstof, ''::text)))
                                             Filter: (voorraadhoudend_jn = 'J'::text)
                                             Rows Removed by Filter: 0
                                 ->  Hash  (cost=13240.55..13240.55 rows=11885 width=74) (actual time=245.430..245.430 rows=45319 loops=1)
                                       Buckets: 2048  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2645kB
                                       ->  Subquery Scan on v40  (cost=12973.14..13240.55 rows=11885 width=74) (actual time=186.156..222.042 rows=45319 loops=1)
                                             ->  HashAggregate  (cost=12973.14..13121.70 rows=11885 width=25) (actual time=186.154..209.633 rows=45319 loops=1)
                                                   ->  Seq Scan on voorraad vrr  (cost=0.00..12340.71 rows=63243 width=25) (actual time=0.453..126.361 rows=62655 loops=1)
                                                         Filter: (status = 'A'::text)
                                                         Rows Removed by Filter: 113953
 Total runtime: 12742.125 ms
(36 rows)
```

Comment: Please add the result of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for both queries to the question.

Comment: I added the output of both explain analyses

Comment: Unrelated, but: Postgres 9.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.